# SQL: Checking if a number within range of multiple ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say we have 2 tables.

```
Table Values
Id   Group    Value
--------------------
A     X        15  
B     Y        55

Table Ranges
Group   LowLimit     HighLimit
--------------------------------
X         0             10       
X         20            30 
Y         30            40 
Y         50            60
```

I would like to check which Values.Id has value that falls outside the LowLimit and HighLimit of the group it belongs to in Ranges (notice each group has multiple ranges).

The desired result would be

```
Table Result
Id
--------------
A    (because the value 15 is outside the range of both (0..10) and (20..30) 
while B is not part of the result because it is within the range of (50..60) even though it is outside the range of (30..40))
```

What would the sql would be like?

Comment: use `NOT EXISTS` . If you are not familiar with this, refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

Comment: the NOT EXISTS suggestion works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option uses an exists query:

```
SELECT
    v.ID
FROM [Values] v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Ranges] r
                  WHERE v.[Group] = r.[Group] AND
                        v.[Value] BETWEEN r.[LowLimit] AND r.[HighLimit]);
```

### Demo

In plain English, this will check each `ID` row from `Values` and check it there does not exist even one range which contains the value.  If no such range exists, then this non matching `ID` would be reported.