# Casting/Filtering string for doing numeric comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table Values
Id     Code       FileNum     LowLim     HighLim
------------------------------------------------

A     N18:35        18         30         40
B     N20:20        18         30         40
```

The Code column is to store codes in string with format of N[filenum]:[value].
How to effectively formatting/splitting these codes for numeric comparison?

-would like to compare the [fileNum] part of the code to the FileNum

-would like to check the [value] part of the code if it falls within the LowLim and HighLim range.

The expected result would be

```
Id

----
A     (because A's code [filenum] 18 matches the fileNum 18 and [value] 35 is within the range of the limits (30..40),
```

B would not be in the result because the code's [filenum] 20 doesn't match its fileNum 18 even though the [value] 20 falls within the range of (30..40)

I have tried to use left, right and replace but none can be called elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: How `elegant` you want ? Please show us your existing query

Comment: what happen to your other question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413289/sql-checking-if-a-number-within-range-of-multiple-ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that'll work so long as Code is in the format Nx:y where x and y can be integers of any length. So, N18:35 will work, but so will N1289:34872.

Sample DDL & DML statements:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID CHAR(1), Code VARCHAR(25), 
    FileNum INT, LowLim INT, HighLim INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('A', 'N18:35', 18, 30, 40),
('B', 'N20:20', 18, 30, 40),
('C', 'N1289:34872', 1289, 34000, 35000)
```

Nested CTEs to split the Code value into FileNumPart and LimitPart values, first by removing the 'N', and then by using CHARINDEX to split either side of the colon, and finally, a conditional select statement:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, REPLACE(Code, 'N', '') AS Code
    FROM @tbl
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX(':', Code) - 1) AS FileNumPart
    ,SUBSTRING(Code, CHARINDEX(':', Code) + 1, LEN(Code) - CHARINDEX(':', Code)) AS LimitPart
    FROM cte
)
SELECT t.ID
FROM cte2
INNER JOIN @tbl t ON cte2.ID = t.ID
WHERE t.FileNum = cte2.FileNumPart AND cte2.LimitPart BETWEEN t.LowLim AND t.HighLim
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from val where substring(code, 2, CHARINDEX(':', code) - 2) = FileNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the table name is `Test`

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Test 
WHERE (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code,':',1),2)=FileNum) and 
      (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code,':',-1),1)>=LowLim and 
      (SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code,':',-1),1)<=HighLim)
```