# SQL Check if value in Table is in range of 2 columns in another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check whether a value in TABLE_1 is in a range based on 2 columns in TABLE_2. I am able to accomplish based on the answer provided in question [SQL: Checking if a number within range of multiple ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51413326/5525619) however when I used this method with a large dataset (~40K rows in both tables) it is maxing out CPU on my SQL server and the query takes an excess of 3 minutes. Is there a way to optimize this query and to limit the CPU that the query uses? If not, is there an alternate query that might be more efficient.

TABLE_1:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TABLE_1;
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | FRUIT   | COUNT |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | Apples  |  2314 |
|  2 | Oranges |  3412 |
|  3 | Oranges |  1296 |
|  4 | Apples  |  2230 |
|  5 | Apples  |  5293 |
|  6 | Oranges |  1994 |
+----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

TABLE_2:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TABLE_2;
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| ID | FRUIT   | START_RANGE | END_RANGE |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Apples  |        2300 |      2400 |
|  2 | Apples  |        7000 |      8000 |
|  3 | Oranges |        1296 |      1296 |
|  4 | Apples  |        5000 |      6000 |
|  5 | Oranges |        9000 |      9999 |
|  6 | Oranges |        8000 |      9000 |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2
                  WHERE TABLE_1.FRUIT = TABLE_2.FRUIT 
                  AND TABLE_1.COUNT BETWEEN TABLE_2.START_RANGE AND TABLE_2.END_RANGE);
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | FRUIT   | COUNT |
+----+---------+-------+
|  2 | Oranges |  3412 |
|  4 | Apples  |  2230 |
|  6 | Oranges |  1994 |
+----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `not exists` is likely the best performing version, but you can try the `left join` equivalent:

```
select table1.*
from Table1
left join table2
on table1.fruit = table2.fruit
and table1.count between table2.start_range and table2.end_range
where table2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2
                  WHERE TABLE_1.FRUIT = TABLE_2.FRUIT AND
                        TABLE_1.COUNT BETWEEN TABLE_2.START_RANGE AND TABLE_2.END_RANGE);
```

For performance, start with an index on `TABLE_2(FRUIT, START_RANGE, END_RANGE)`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to SQL. I'm not sure how to modify to start with an index. Do you mean to replace `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2` with `SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_2(FRUIT, START_RANGE, END_RANGE)`?

Comment: @MBasith . . . If you create the index, the database will probably use it for the query.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding an index on `table_2.fruit` (as @Gordon already suggested), you might try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_1
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT tab1.id
                  FROM   table_1 tab1
                  JOIN   table_2 tab2
                    ON   tab1.fruit = tab2.fruit
                   AND   tab1.count BETWEEN tab2.start_range AND tab2.end_range);
```

This of course supposes that `ID` if the primary key.